# JPA Specification to get multiple filtered result to be combined

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pagination, specifications

I am working on spring boot project, in which some results list are to be displayed based on permissions of user.

All data is kept at DB, for example :

table : myModel

| modelName | modelStatus | modelDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | AA | 2022-12-23 |
| 14 | AB | 2021-10-23 |
| 16 | AA | 2022-01-02 |
| 17 | PF | 2021-11-17 |
| 100 | AA | 2023-11-04 |
| 102 | AB | 2020-12-30 |
| 112 | PF | 2022-06-03 |
| 114 | AB | 2022-12-01 |
| 120 | PF | 2021-05-03 |
| 141 | AB | 2022-02-04 |
| 142 | AA | 2022-04-28 |
| 154 | AB | 2022-09-22 |

So I need to show the list of myModel based on PF status + modelDate Desc at top first then remaining models to be add at down as per modelDate Desc too. For example

| modelName | modelStatus | modelDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 112 | PF | 2022-06-03 |
| 17 | PF | 2021-11-17 |
| 120 | PF | 2021-05-03 |
| 100 | AA | 2023-11-04 |
| 12 | AA | 2022-12-23 |
| 114 | AB | 2022-12-01 |
| 154 | AB | 2022-09-22 |
| 142 | AA | 2022-04-28 |
| 141 | AB | 2022-02-04 |
| 16 | AA | 2022-01-02 |
| 14 | AB | 2021-10-23 |
| 102 | AB | 2020-12-30 |

This can be done with query but here I have to :

1. Do in pagination.
2. It will have other filters along with above handling of showing PF at top.

So I need some specification so that other filter can easily be joined.

Currently I have implemented like -

- Get the list of Non-PF  - NonPFModelList
- Get the list of PF - PFMdelList

Then combined result based on page request of spring boot. But some where my code is breaking when I have

"PageNumber": 1,
"PageSize": 10,

My PFMdelList have 2 records and NonPFModelList has 10 original records but I have to append 8 as my pagination is for 10 records per page.
When pageNumber=2 will come the it will omit last page's two records and bring next page 10 nonPFAList records.

How can I handled all this with specification?